# cannot use imageQt to cast Image to QImage

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pyside, typeerror

```
st.img.save('./test.png', 'PNG')
img = Image.open('./test.png')
self.imgQ = ImageQt(img)
pixMap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.imgQ)
```

It shows typeError here:

```
    pixMap = QPixmap.fromImage(self.imgQ)
TypeError: 'PySide.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt)
Supported signatures:
  PySide.QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(PySide.QtGui.QImage, PySide.QtCore.Qt.ImageConversionFlags = Qt.AutoColor)
```

I think the `ImageQt` would convert the `Image` to `QImage`. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ImageQt` module contains a subclass of `QImage`, which it imports from `PyQt`, not `PySide`.

In order to get `ImageQt` to use `PySide`, you could try a little hack, like this:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui
sys.modules['PyQt4.QtGui'] = QtGui
# or if you have PyQt5 installed, you might need this
# sys.modules['PyQt5.QtGui'] = QtGui
from PIL import ImageQt
```

Comment: Thanks! it solves my problem! By the way, I met another problem. one of the image Shown in QGraphicsview is distorted. Do you know the possibly reason? It's okay if you don't want to answer this question.

Comment: @BadEggX. I don't the answer from your description. Perhaps you should post anther question with more information.